# Kendo-UI autocomplete fails to load

Tags: kendo-ui

I am having an issue with the data source not being accessed. The webservice executes it's query and firebug shows the return string but I don't get the features of the autocomplete list.

```
    $("#txtCriteria").kendoAutoComplete({
    minLength: 1,
    suggest: true,
    filter: "startswith",
    dataTextField: "ACName",
    select: function (e) {
      var  dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
        //output selected dataItem
        document.getElementsByName("hdfldSelect")[0].value = dataItem.ACCode;
        $("#txtCriteria").kendoAutoComplete();
        var autocomplete = $("#txtCriteria").data("kendoAutoComplete");
        autocomplete.destroy();
    },
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "../DAL/Reports/wsReports.asmx/AutoComplete",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "GET",
            },
            parameterMap: function (data, action) {
                var newParams = {
                    Type: Type,
                    filter: data.filter.filters[0].value
                };//var
                return newParams;
            },//parameter
        }//trans2
    })//data
});
```

Thank you for any assistance

Comment: does the remote source return data? is the remote url getting called correctly?

Comment: show us the json repsonse ? if the data is confidential, then create dummy  that similar to it maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Going along the fact that your endpoint returns the expected data set, you could try adding a 'schema' to your kendo-datasource.

```
dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    schema: {
                        data: function (e) {
                            return e.Results
                        },
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                Id: { type: "number" },
                                Name: { type: "string" }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "../DAL/Reports/wsReports.asmx/AutoComplete",
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "GET",
                        },
                        parameterMap: function (data, action) {
                            var newParams = {
                                Type: Type,
                                filter: data.filter.filters[0].value
                            };//var
                            return newParams;
                        },//parameter
                    }//trans2
                })//data
```